# Putting empty array values '[]' into postgres text[] column from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am having an issue using sqlalchemy and python to write some vaules to a postgres table that has a text[] column. The issue is when I go to put in an empty array. The error that comes back is `<class 'sqlalchemy.exc.DataError'>, DataError('(psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) malformed array literal: "[]"`

The column is called `reply_to`and is of datatype text[]. If there is a value, it gets inserted into the table no problem. if there is nothing in the dataframe for that column (represented as `[]`) it fails with the error above. Im not sure how to manipulate the value so that it goes into the table. I have tried:

`data["reply_to"] = data['reply_to'].replace('[]', '{}')`

`data["reply_to"] = data['reply_to'].replace('[]', None)`

`data.iloc[i:i + 1].to_sql(name=table, if_exists='append', con=db, index=False, dtype={'reply_to': sqlalchemy.types.JSON})`

I have to admit, I don't fully understand what the issue is.

```py
def write_data(table, data):
    conn_string = 'postgresql://creds/cryptodb'
    params = config()
    db = create_engine(conn_string)
    conn = db.connect()
    conn1 = psycopg2.connect(**params)
    if table == 'price_action_btc':
        data.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
        data.rename(columns={'Datetime': 'datetime', 'Open': 'open', 'Close': 'close', 'High': 'high', 'Low': 'low',
                             'Adj Close': 'adj_close', 'Volume': 'volume'}, inplace=True)
    else:
        data.drop('search', axis=1, inplace=True)
        data["conversation_id"] = pd.to_numeric(data["conversation_id"])
        data["created_at"] = pd.to_numeric(data["created_at"])
        data["date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["date"])
        data["retweet_date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["retweet_date"])
        data["user_id"] = pd.to_numeric(data["user_id"])
        data["day"] = pd.to_numeric(data["day"])
        data["hour"] = pd.to_numeric(data["hour"])
        data["video"] = pd.to_numeric(data["video"])
        data["nlikes"] = pd.to_numeric(data["nlikes"])
        data["nreplies"] = pd.to_numeric(data["nreplies"])
        data["nretweets"] = pd.to_numeric(data["nretweets"])
        data["retweet_id"] = pd.to_numeric(data["retweet_id"])
        data["user_rt_id"] = pd.to_numeric(data["user_rt_id"])
        # data["reply_to"] = data['reply_to'].replace('[]', '{}')
    for i in range(len(data)):
        try:
            data.iloc[i:i + 1].to_sql(name=table, if_exists='append', con=db, index=False, dtype={'reply_to': sqlalchemy.types.JSON})
        except exc.IntegrityError:
            pass
    conn1.commit()
    conn1.close()
```

data is a dataframe, and this is an example of its data:

```
data['reply_to']
0                                                      []
1                                                      []
2       [{'screen_name': 'insiliconot', 'name': '핀핟핤핚핝...
3                                                      []
4                                                      []
                              ...                        
9995                                                   []
```

Comment: It would be easier to offer suggestions if we could see the broken code.

Comment: I added the method, and an example of what the incoming data looks like (relative to the column in question)

Comment: It looks like you want that field to be JSONB, not text[].  So, just make the field be JSONB, not text[].